# Error happen when implementing datagridview cell click in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a problem with datagridview even handler, when I click at the cell i want the value in that cell send to text box, it was work but after i change something that i forgot it can't work. I've try to recreate the datagridview and its event handler but nothing. This is my code

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].ToString();
    }
```

[image]

do you have any idea to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
 textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: wualla, I forget that word. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
private void gridview_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  int r = e.RowIndex;
  llenartextbox(r);
}

public void llenartextbox(int index)
{
  textbox.Text = gridview.rows[index].Cells["Cliente"].Value.ToString();
}
```